# Not able to insert Data in ignite DB from Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using the PutDatabaseRecord processor but  I am not able to insert/update data in ignite DB.

Error:- Suppose the public is my DB name and emp is my table name. then an error message is coming public.emp is not found but in my ignite DB emp table is exist in public DB.

I am using the DBCPConnectionpool controller as a connection with DB.

So, the same approach when I am using MySQL then I am able to insert/update/delete data in DB.

Please help me with how I can insert/select/update/delete data in ignite DB from NIFI. Is there is any other approach to do this?

Please let me know if you require any further info.

Thanks,

Avinash kr.

kumaravi256@gmail.com

8700024522

Comment: Not required to give email and mobile no here.

Comment: please edit your question and provide: the error stacktrace from log file, parameters of  PutDatabaseRecord, parameters of DBCPConnectionpool.